# Найти кординаты элемента на изображений

Tags: python

у меня есть графический элемент, как с помощью python узнать есть ли данный элемент на другом изображении, и если он есть, как  определить координаты?

Comment: Посмотрите http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709414/how-to-detect-if-image-is-present-on-screen